# Design pattern regarding generic controller / services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, service

Working on some designoptions for an mvc + web api application. The question i would like to ask is mor or less 'how would you do this better, or is the below sound'

We have two services, one crud, and one extended for for entites having support for extended methods. we then have to generic controllers giving the functionality according to the services. Evrything simplified for example.

Note: ICrudService is the interface for CrudService and IExtendedCrudService inherits ICrudService.

```
public class CrudService<T>
{
   protected readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

   public CrudService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
   {
      UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
   }
   //Methods for crud and so forth
}

public class ExtendedCrudService<T> : CrudService<T>
{
   public ExtendedCrudService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
   {
   }
   //Methods for extended functionality
}

public abstract class ControllerBase<T>
{
   private readonly ICrudService<T> _crudService;

   public ControllerBase(ICrudService<T> crudService)
   {
      _crudService = crudService;
   }
   //Actions for crud stuff
}

public abstract ExtendedControllerBase<T> : ControllerBase<T>
{
   private readonly IExtendedCrudService<T> _extCrudService;

   public ExtendedControllerBase(IExtendedCrudService<T> extCrudService) : base(extCrudService)
   {
      _extCrudService = extCrudService;
   }
   //Action for extended stuff
}
```

All extended entities will use the same crud stuff as none extended there of the controller inheritance. Mapping = Automap and DI is used. So would you do this differently, if so how and why? Trying to get a grip on what is mostly used for these kinds of scenarios, so all input deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I use this design pattern quite a bit.  Using interfaces allows for easier (in my opinion) unit testing.  I would recommend creating interfaces for all of your services, and in the class that implements a service, create two constructors - one that takes all of the necessary interfaces as you have above, but also a default constructor that takes a new class - using your CrudService as an example, I would also put in the following:

```
public CrudService() : this(new UnitOfWork())
{
}
```

This would allow you to use parameterless constructors as well as parameterized constructors.